# Django - Custom Auth Class, Token OR Session

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I need to write a class that will provide SessionAuthentication and TokenAuthentication on django-restframework 3.0

That means - if user have a valid session **OR** a valid token he is authenticated.

I have both classes but I have no idea how to combine them:
TOKEN:

```
def authenticate(self, request):

    auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()

    if not auth or auth[0].lower() != self.keyword.lower().encode():
        return None

    if len(auth) == 1:
        msg = _('Invalid token header. No credentials provided.')
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
    elif len(auth) > 2:
        msg = _('Invalid token header. Token string should not contain spaces.')
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
```

SESSION:

```
def authenticate(self, request):
    """
    Returns a `User` if the request session currently has a logged in user.
    Otherwise returns `None`.
    """

    # Get the session-based user from the underlying HttpRequest object
    user = getattr(request._request, 'user', None)

    # Unauthenticated, CSRF validation not required
    if not user or not user.is_active:
        return None
```

I also tried on settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

but it did not work our, I think this is checking token **AND** session..

Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#how-authentication-is-determined, it authenticates with the first authenticator that succeeds

Comment: Thank you! changing the order on     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' worked